MongoDB, how do I speed up my geo-query for a large collection (~20M docs)?
I have a colleciton with ~20M entries. Each document being a GeoJSON object with the following format:
_id: ObjectID,

properties:
   -gml_id: String,
   -....
   -<A few other properties that don't seem helpful for my purposes (e.g. validFrom, ..) />
   -....

geometry:
   -type: "Polygon",
   -coordinates: [(lat_0, lng_0),...(lat_k,lng_k)

I would like to query this collection for a given boundary-box, here is my current code:
app.get('/api/get-by-bbox', async (req, res) => {
  const { north, south, east, west } = req.query;
  try {
    const data = await Plants.find({
      geometry: {
        $geoWithin: {
          $geometry: {
            type: 'Polygon',
            coordinates: [
              [
                [parseFloat(west), parseFloat(south)],
                [parseFloat(east), parseFloat(south)],
                [parseFloat(east), parseFloat(north)],
                [parseFloat(west), parseFloat(north)],
                [parseFloat(west), parseFloat(south)],
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      }    });


    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

I have tried using $geoIntersects but no noticeable difference...the query takes 10minutes!! I have a plantSchema.index({ geometry: '2dsphere' }); defined in the Plant model document...and given the size and this is in development it is all running off my local machine, which means I am not benefitting from sharding I guess?
Should I perhaps rely on 3rd party libraries for a more practical solution (such as h3?) - although this means adding a hexagon property to each 20M records which is expensive in itself? Any suggestions welcome...

Can you verify the 2dsphere index was created successfully?

I have done so, in MongoCompass in the indexes tab for the collection, I have: "geometry (2dsphere)"
